# how to grab picture from camera in android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am creating an image editor android app. I need to grab the image captured by the camera on the app without it saving in a directory first. I am using this way to capture the image right now :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent camera_intent = new  Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
    startActivity (camera_intent);
}
```

A button invokes the intent and I then have to go to the directory and open the image from there. What can I do for it to not save in any directory unless explicitly asked by the user ?

Comment: Have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_camera.htm).. beware that the camera intent result may change for different phone models